# RegisterStartupScript not behaving as expected with jQuery script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a Page with an update panel, in this update panel I have a button that I want to show/hide by outputting JavaScript given some params, I am using for example:

```
RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), 
  "deleteHideScript", "$('.deleteButton').hide();", True)
```

I am able to run the `$('.deleteButton').hide();` bit in the console and get the desired effect.  I am also able to output a script in the same way to `console.log('imHere');` and get the expected behavior.

What am I missing?

Comment: is the button in the update panel?

Comment: @RossDargan yes, as mentioned above the button is within the update panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial rendering is the problem. You can't register a startup script to show an alert after an asynchronous postback. You'll have to find another way of achieving the same effect, or perform a full postback when you need to display the alert.

You can try setting `EnablePageHeadUpdate="true"`, but I can't guarantee that will have any effect.

**EDIT**

Because of partial rendering, the script is run before the button is rendered, which is causing your issue. If you can find a way to render the button before the script is executed, you should be all set.

Comment: I mentioned that I am able to add a script that writes to the log just fine using the same approach.  So I know that registering works in some cases.

Comment: Writing to the log is not the same as displaying an alert on the page.

Comment: I guess my JS noobness is showing through, I am hiding a button not displaying any sort of alert, is alert a concept that has escaped me?

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I got you mixed up with another question! Is the  button you're trying to hide in an update panel? Even if it is, I don't know if you can write to the document in an asychronous postback.

Comment: so you pointed me down the right path, it seems partial rendering was the problem, basically the script was getting rendered and ran before the button was actually rendered.  Please amend your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've amended my answer to reflect your findings. Glad you got it figured out :)

Comment: If the button is available after a partial update then ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript will probably work as it will execute the given script even in an async postback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the script is injected **before** the jQuery script tag.

Something like that is possible if you are using a `ScriptManager` to reference the script.

You can move the jQuery reference into the `<head>` or use [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) method.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: @djsolid No, the jQuery script is above all other scripts when rendered. Thanks for trying.